# Подскажите как правильно инициализировать библиотеку sberzvuk-api в nodejs

Tags: node.js

Есть такая библиотека https://github.com/Aiving/sberzvuk-api
У нее очень краткая документация
Не пойму как её инициализировать в проекте на nodejs

```
var sberzvuk = require('sberzvuk-api')
const zvuk = new sberzvuk({ token: 'lXQAq5W3DrZKEH3l9B8tDJjXUDDA1sQC' });
```

на такой вызов ругается **TypeError: sberzvuk is not a constructor**

Прошу совета у опытных программистов, как ее правильно инициализировать и использовать, например запрос search?

Comment: А вы уверены, что возвращается функция или класс, который надо вызывать через new?

Comment: Я новичок в node, поэтому плохо понимаю что там эта библиотека экспортирует. Нужно исходники поизучать, мне они мало о чем говорят

Comment: `new ZvukAPI({token: ...})` ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот как то так это должно выглядеть

```
import sber from 'sberzvuk-api';

const zv = new sber.ZvukAPI('lXQAq5W3DrZKEH3l9B8tDJjXUDDA1sQC')

zv.search('ария') // Ищем исполнителя
  .then(res => {
    // Ищем нужный альбом
    return res.tracks.filter(x => x.name.indexOf('Герой') !== -1)[0];
  })
  .then(res => {
    // Вытаскиваем ID песен
    return res.album.tracks;
  })
  .then(res => {
    // Запрашиваем песни из альбома
    const songs = [];
    res.forEach(item => songs.push(zv.getTrack(item)))
    return Promise.all(songs);
  })
  .then(res => {
    // Выводим названия песен
    res.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item.title)
    })
  })
```

Соглашусь, документация оставляет желать лучшего...

Comment: плохая идея, писать `album.album.tracks.forEach( async item`

Comment: да и вообще, ваш ответ не запускается из-за отсутствия async в ресолвере первого промиса, а потом падает из-за того, что вы используете `album.album` там, где его нет и из-за того, что переменная album - массив

Comment: @nörbörnën Поправил и обновил